# JSP send string parameter that has html content

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to pass a string parameter that has html content in it.

```
<%
String myparam = "<td>some text</td>";
%>
<td>
<a href="page.jsp?myparam=<%=myparam%>">Visit W3Schools</a>
</td
```

It fails to send and recognizes my string as html code.

Comment: use ajax call for complete this task

Comment: So its not possible to do it using jsp

Comment: try like this `<a href=<%= "page.jsp?myparam="<%=myparam%>"" %> >Visit</a>`

Comment: was a mistake. Still does not work with equal sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a text into URL passable parameters, *and* to have no HTML `<`, `>` inside of the HTML attribute, do:

```
String myparam = URLEncoder.encode("<td>some text</td>", "UTF-8");
```

At the top of the JSP you maybe have to import java.net.URLEncoder.

```
<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be indeed possible.
To insert the value of a variable, use

```
<%= %>
```

like this:

```
<a href="page.jsp?myparam=<%=myparam%>">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

But sending html inside a url is not a good idea. It´s easy to manipulate and you will get security issues due to code injection.

And if you really really need to send html in the url, you need to escape the html specific characters.

Comment: I had placed the equal sign just left it out by mistake. Still does not work with edit. If its not possible then i will look for another way